# AsyncImage not loading : Coil-Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, imageurl, coil

I have a Jetpack Compose app that makes a call to the [Picsum API](https://picsum.photos/) (endpoint: https://picsum.photos/v2/list) and tries to display them in a `LazyList` using the Coil library (`2.1.0`). I have the typical Retrofit2 + OkHttp3 setup, and am able to get all the necessary data, including the required image URL, from the endpoint. So far so good.

However, despite having valid image URLs, I am not able to display the image in the view. I've tried both `AsyncImage` and `Image` with `rememberAsyncImagePainter` but to no avail. I even tried hard-coding the URL string, but it still doesn't display anything. I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Similar posts mention the INTERNET permission, but I already have it in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Here is the [link to my github project](https://github.com/kcdev90/PhotoViewer), and below are snippets of relevant code:

##### PhotoCard.kt

```
@Composable
fun PhotoCard(photo: Photo, ... ) {
    ...
    Image(
        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(photo.url),
        ...
    )
}
```

##### PhotoListViewModel.kt

```
class PhotoListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getPhotoListUseCase: GetPhotoListUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _pageState = MutableStateFlow(PageState<Photo>())
    val pageState = _pageState.asStateFlow()

    fun loadPhotoList(loadNextPage: Boolean = false) {
        ...
        getPhotoListUseCase.invoke().let { response ->
            if (response == null) {
                ...
            } else {
                _pageState.update {
                    it.copy(data = response, isInflight = false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

##### PhotoListRepository.kt

```
interface PhotoListRepository {
    suspend fun getPhotoList(): List<Photo>?
}
```

##### PhotoListApi.kt

```
interface PhotoListApi {
    @GET("v2/list")
    suspend fun getPhotoList(): List<Photo>?
}
```

##### Photo.kt

```
data class Photo(
    val id: String,
    val author: String,
    val width: Int,
    val height: Int,
    val url: String,
    val download_url: String
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in the API `url` is not the direct image link. It is basically the page url of the image.

Use `photo.download_url` instead of `photo.url`

Comment: Oh... I feel rather silly now...